# Mono's Array.Copy unnecessarily boxing in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, mono

I'm noticing that Array.Copy will cause massive heap allocations when used on multidimensional arrays. Specifically, consider the following:

```
static void Test()
{
    int size = 100;
    byte[,] source = new byte[size, size];
    byte[,] target = new byte[size, size];
    Copy(source, target);
}

static void Copy(byte[,] source, byte[,] target)
{
    System.Array.Copy(source, target, source.Length);
}
```

The copy method is producing 332 KB of garbage.

Digging deeper, it all comes from a method GetValueImpl. I checked the mono source code (I'm using a mono compiler for this) and it seems Array.Copy first tries to do a FastCopy (haven't been able to find its implementation) and if that fails, it ends up doing

```
Object srcval = sourceArray.GetValueImpl (source_pos + i);
```

For every element in the array. The number of bytes (332K) corresponds exactly to the amount produced by boxing every element in both arrays.

If I replace the 2d arrays with 1d arrays of length 10000, this does not happen: my Copy method produces no allocations. Am I missing something or is this a bug?